# Can we develop desktop applications in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, desktop-application

I want to develop Desktop and Android applications. And I want to learn kotlin for this. Kotlin is mostly used for developing Android applications but I want to know that can we develop desktop applications in kotlin?

Comment: “Kotlin is mostly used for developing Android applications” — a common view, but not entirely accurate.  Lots of people use Kotlin for server-side systems, web front-ends, web back-ends, desktop apps, libraries and frameworks, data analysis, and many other things.  JVM and Android are targetted about equally; details [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/devecosystem-2020/kotlin/).

Comment: "Is it possible to ____?" is generally considered too broad to be a good question for Stack Overflow—the answer is usually: "yes, it's probably possible, but describing how to do it would entail designing a large piece of software." Instead, you should try to build it, and ask a question when you encounter a specific problem. Please see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) for more information.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can. Technically any program you can write in Java can also be written in Kotlin*. Of course it's even better when using frameworks that were specially tailored for Kotlin.

There are frameworks like [TornadoFX](https://tornadofx.io/) built on top of JavaFX to build desktop UIs.

More recently, [Compose](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose/) has been generalized for Desktop apps (initially JetPack Compose for Android).

**More specifically, Kotlin/JVM compiles to Java bytecode, so you can use Kotlin to target any environment running a JVM that interprets this bytecode (provided the target bytecode version is at most that of the JVM, like in Java).
As pointed out by @Tenfour04, GWT is not in this category because it directly works on the Java source code, not bytecode.*

Comment: Except for GWT. You can write in Java but not Kotlin because GWT “compiles” Java to JavaScript.

Comment: @Tenfour04 fair enough. Will rephrase

Comment: It is 2023 and Compose is still missing a lot of basic stuff and buggy.